# Call https api get error in .net docker compose file

Tags: docker, ssl, .net-core, docker-compose

I have .net core 7 solution which is dockerized in a compose file like below:

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  sqldb:
    image: mcr.microsoft.com/azure-sql-edge
    ports:
      - "1433:1433"
    environment:
      - SA_PASSWORD=PASSWORD
      - ACCEPT_EULA=Y

  product-api:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}productapi
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: src/productapi/WebApi/Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      - "sqldb"

  live-api:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}live
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: src/LiveAPI/Web/Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      - "sqldb"
      - "product-api"
```

and a compose override like below:

```
version: '3.4'

services:    
  product-api:
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
      - ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://+:443;http://+:80
    ports:
      - "5200:443"
      - "5201:80"
    volumes:
      - ${APPDATA}/Microsoft/UserSecrets:/root/.microsoft/usersecrets:ro
      - ${APPDATA}/ASP.NET/Https:/root/.aspnet/https:ro

  live-api:
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
      - ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://+:443;http://+:80
    ports:
      - "5300:443"
    volumes:
      - ${APPDATA}/Microsoft/UserSecrets:/root/.microsoft/usersecrets:ro
      - ${APPDATA}/ASP.NET/Https:/root/.aspnet/https:ro
```

So, when I try to call rest api in "product-api" from "live-api" service, I get the following exception:

> The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.
> -> The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure: RemoteCertificateNameMismatch, RemoteCertificateChainErrors

I tried many solutions, but none of them has been worked for me!

What I tried:

Disable SSL validation in "live-api" service.

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (sender, certificate, chain, errors) =>
            {
                // local dev, just approve all certs
                if (development) return true;
                return errors == SslPolicyErrors.None;
            };
```

How I tried to call the API:

- https://product-api:443
- https://product-api
- https://host.docker.internal:5200

Comment: Before trying more solutions, tell me now what is the root cause of that error based on your investigation? If you don't know that yet, then trying more is useless.

Comment: @LexLi Actually, I don't know.

Comment: 1. Verify what’s the certificate configured for product-api and see if you replace it with a valid one with your network administrators. 2. Even if you need to disable TLS validation , instead of fixing certificate, you should identify the actual line of code that triggers the exception on caller side. Things like `HttpClient` have their own ways to skip validation, so merely changing `ServicePointManager` isn’t right.

Comment: @LexLi I am using restsharp library for http requests, I tried another solution as in https://stackoverflow.com/a/56351003/3096477 and it didn't work as well. With certificate I need more time while I'm not expert in it.